# Unable to copy image to clipboard in Firefox Addon development

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

I'm developing a Firefox Addon which has this functionality to copy an image to clipboard.
I'm using require("sdk/clipboard") lib, as described in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/clipboard)

But when I try to attach a base64 image, it gives me the following error:

```
JPM [error]   Message: Error: Invalid flavor for image/jpg
```

You can find an example of a command that tries to copy an image to the clipboard and is giving me thie error here: https://jsfiddle.net/g0Lff2b5/

When I try to use the example in the website, it works. I think that perhaps my base64 is invalid, even though I used many base64 generators, and setting this base64 into a  tag works fine.

Anly ideas?

Comment: Oh thats interesting, i dont know why your method doesnt work, it seems to match the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I did a workaround fix that solves for now, but the main problem remain.

What I did in order to copy the image to the clipboard was to create a canvas object, add the image to it, and call the function that converts the image to a BASE64 string (.toDataURL('image/png')). then, I was able to copy this base64 to the clipboard.